# ElasticSearch Parent/Child Restriction

Tags: elasticsearch

The Elastic 2.2 documentation states:

> **Parent-child restrictions**
>
> The parent and child types must be different — parent-child
>   relationships cannot be established between documents of the same
>   type.

If that is a restriction, then go do you go about mapping a tree of sorts that will have the same type for each child recursively.  For example, a Human object that may have a child that's also a Human, and that may also have a child that's a Human, etc, etc.

Is there some alternative to Parent/Child relationships that should be used here?

Comment: You can handle it manually by adding `parentId` field in your document.

Comment: So in that case, I would not do a parent/child relationship at all, but would just have each object have a parent_id field?  If so, would there be a good way, in a single query, to start at some node, and return it and its parent, then its parent, etc., until I encounter a node that doesn't have a value in parentId?

Comment: No, I don't think that would be possible in just one query..